# Using \u221A does NOT display a square root symbol on my mac when using eclipse. why?

Tags: java

placing \u221A in a string and writing a System.out.println statement should display a square root symbol on the screen. right? Well the problem is when doing just that with my mac (using eclipse), I get a '?' instead of a square root symbol. What's up with that? here's some sample code to illustrate what I mean:

```
System.out.println("Error: cannot compute \u221A of negative numbers. Feature not supported!");
```

My output basically ends up looking like this:

> Error: cannot compute ? of negative numbers. Feature not supported

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's not in your font. What font are you using?

Comment: You mean what fond eclipse is using in the console during program execution? I have no idea since I do not even know how to check that. I could check what font i'm using in the editing window inside eclipse, but the two are probably unrelated. right?

Comment: Can you write a plain HTML document with the code `&#x221A` and produce a radical sign?

Comment: Check the charset set in your IDE (if you are using one). If not set, set it to `UTF-8`. If not using any IDE then compile the code with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` option.

Comment: I checked the charset and turns out my file was encoded in ASCII by default in eclipse! thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you set up your eclipse to support the UTF-8 encoded characters. 
Go to **Windows  -> Prefereces -> General -> Workspace**

On the workspace screen, you will see Text file encoding, by default the Default(Cp1525) is selected. Choose the Other option and from the drop down select UTF-8.

Then press Apply and OK. Shown in the below image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a limitation of the [MacRoman font charset](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714). Something like this should work:

```
String unicodeMessage =
    "\u7686\u3055\u3093\u3001\u3053\u3093\u306b\u3061\u306f";

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println(unicodeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change console output encoding to to UTF-8

Run -> Run Configuratons -> Common -> Encoding -> UTF-8